# Grails forward() Causes StackOverflow Error

Tags: grails

In the current version of grails (3.1.1, Feb 2016), using forward() inside of a controller is causing a stack overflow.  Note that using redirect() works fine, but I have a requirement that the URL cannot change.  Why is this StackOverflow being generated?

My exact requirement is to check the request.forwardURI against a list in the database, and if it matches send the data back for that object (as JSON, XML, HTML) without changing the user's browser URL.  So my attempt to solve this was to use a custom 404 error handler which checks to see if the requestURI matches anything, and issue a forward() in that case.  (NOTE: I've also tried doing the same thing in a matchAll() Interceptor, but had the same result).  The logic works great if I use redirect() instead of forward(), but it changes the browser URL and that is a no-go for me - I must retain the original browser URL.

I've got [a sample application you can run in github](https://github.com/gte250p/grails-3.1.1_forward-error) to recreate the bug, but the relevant parts are given here.

Inside of UrlMappings.groovy, we send the 404 request to a custom Error handler:

```
...
"404"(controller: 'error', action:'notFound')
...
```

Next, in the ErrorController.groovy:notFound(), we have some custom logic which issues the forward if necessary [not exactly my requirement, but close]:

```
def notFound() {
    if( request.forwardURI.contains("foo") ){ // This special case should be forwarded to the foo controller.
        log.warn("User requested Foo, sending to FooController...");
        forward(controller: 'foo', action: 'index');
        return;
    }
    // Now we can say it is not found for sure, and show error
}
```

My current work around is to actually issue a REST call from within my controller to another controller and return the data (avoid any redirect or forward call), which makes cringe each time I think of it.

Comment: If you do use `redirect()`, can it find that page? The StackOverflow is most likely caused because it gets in an infinite loop/recursion. It endlessly tries to find a controller, still gets a 404, goes to the same method and so on. (That's why I added the previous line, so maybe it didn't see it as a 404 anymore)

Comment: @Ivar It can find the page without a problem using redirect() and everything works like you would expect it to.  The only downside is that it violates my requirement that the URL not change.

Comment: In case anyone cares here is the bug I opened on grails-core: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is some sort of bug, the code above should work.

Graeme has added it as a blocker to 3.0.15.

Comment: In case anyone cares, it was solved in 3.1.2 according to my tests.